# Facebook Business is verified but can't request advanced access for permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

I want to request advanced access for the email permission on the Facebook developer portal in order to make my 'login with facebook' work again in my apps.
However when I want to do so I get this hover-popup saying that my business should be verified. However that is the case...
[image: Email permission I want to request]
[image: Proof my business has been validated in August already]
I do can click the button to request the access, when doing so it tells me my Android play store privacy URL should be set and valid (which is, I checked...)! Then clicking it again allows me to request but then afterwards nothing is requested....
[image: I can ask for the permission but thats it]

Any idea how I could get out of this 'loop' or how I can get in touch with Facebook to solve the issue?